# Neo4j Server plugin - Plugin does not show up in extensions

Tags: java, neo4j

Following the instruction on the neo4j website for building a server extension, i cannot get the plugin to show in the list of available extensions.

This is the content of my jar which i placed in the plugins directory of neo4j:

META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin
example/
example/GetAll.class
example/GetAll.java

The file org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin contains the string example.GetAll. The code for GetAll.java was taken directly from the Neo4j website (see below). Any help would be much appreciated.

Neo4j verison: 2.1.3 (installed with Homebrew on OSX - 10.8.5)

code:

```
package example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Description;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Name;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginTarget;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Source;
import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations;

@Description( "An extension to the Neo4j Server for getting all nodes or relationships" )
public class GetAll extends ServerPlugin
{
    @Name( "get_all_nodes" )
    @Description( "Get all nodes from the Neo4j graph database" )
    @PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
    public Iterable<Node> getAllNodes( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
        {
            for ( Node node : GlobalGraphOperations.at( graphDb ).getAllNodes() )
            {
                nodes.add( node );
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        return nodes;
    }

    @Description( "Get all relationships from the Neo4j graph database" )
    @PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
    public Iterable<Relationship> getAllRelationships( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
    {
        List<Relationship> rels = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
        {
            for ( Relationship rel : GlobalGraphOperations.at( graphDb ).getAllRelationships() )
            {
                rels.add( rel );
            }
            tx.success();
        }
        return rels;
    }
}
```

log entries from starting the server - 
console.log:

```
2014-08-09 13:46:27.743+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on -1
2014-08-09 13:46:28.869+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2014-08-09 13:46:28.925+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 80 threads available
2014-08-09 13:46:29.097+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
2014-08-09 13:46:29.184+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted discovery module at [/]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.192+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted REST API at [/db/data/]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.195+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted management API at [/db/manage/]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.195+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted webadmin at [/webadmin]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.195+0000 INFO  [API] Mounted Neo4j Browser at [/browser]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.247+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2014-08-09 13:46:29.292+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
14:46:29.295 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40e74e3{/,null,null} contextPath ends with /
14:46:29.295 [main] WARN  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Empty contextPath
14:46:29.298 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.0.5.v20130815
14:46:29.324 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@3d8c2eeb{/,null,AVAILABLE}
14:46:29.409 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
14:46:29.419 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@24c32994{/webadmin,jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.3/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.1.3-static-web.jar!/webadmin-html,AVAILABLE}
14:46:29.810 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3582d322{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
14:46:30.054 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@558d60a3{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
14:46:30.072 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /browser, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
14:46:30.073 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7aa6ede2{/browser,jar:file:/usr/local/Cellar/neo4j/2.1.3/libexec/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.1.3.jar!/browser,AVAILABLE}
14:46:30.155 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@40e74e3{/,null,AVAILABLE}
14:46:30.164 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@2e85a1ef{HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7474}
14:46:30.520 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@d4a4b67{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7473}
2014-08-09 13:46:30.520+0000 INFO  [API] Server started on: http://localhost:7474/
2014-08-09 13:46:30.521+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
```

neo4j.0.0.log:

```
Aug 09, 2014 2:49:59 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Aug 09, 2014 2:50:00 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Aug 09, 2014 2:50:00 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
```

Comment: did you restart the server after copying the jar file to the plugins folder? Check log files in data/logs for errors.

Comment: @StefanArmbruster Thanks for the quick response - i stopped the sever, placed the .jar into the plugins folder, then restarted server. (I've added the log messages generated when starting the server to the question.)

Comment: Sometimes it helps to have a newline after the classname in the services file

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks, tried adding a newline and still can't get the plugin to show up.

Comment: can you show the content of the jar file: `jar tf myjar.jar` perhaps you can even share the jar on dropbox or so?

Comment: @MichaelHunger Sorted now - silly mistake, has my IDE compiling to java 1.8. Thanks for you help.