# (Another) Neo4j Plugin not showing up in Extentions

Tags: java, scala, neo4j

Like a lot of people with a [Simlar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218412/neo4j-server-plugin-plugin-does-not-show-up-in-extensions), I can''t get my plugin extention to show up:

```
{
  "extensions" : {
  },
  "node" : ...
}
```

## Tried

Compiled GetAll.java using java 1.7. Using SBT, build.sbt:

```
javaOptions ++= Seq( "-source", "1.7" )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "2.1.3" % "provided" withSources(),
  "org.neo4j" % "server-api" % "2.1.3" % "provided" withSources()
)
```

Very simple JAR:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/services/
META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin
GetAll.class
```

Simple GetAll.class:

```
package com.danmacias.neo4j.plugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Description;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Name;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginTarget;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin;
import org.neo4j.server.plugins.Source;
import org.neo4j.tooling.GlobalGraphOperations;

// START SNIPPET: GetAll
package com.danmacias.neo4j.plugin;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
@Description( "An extension to the Neo4j Server for getting all nodes or relationships" )
public class GetAll extends ServerPlugin
{
  @Name( "get_all_nodes" )
  @Description( "Get all nodes from the Neo4j graph database" )
  @PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
  public Iterable<Node> getAllNodes( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb )
  {
    ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx())
    {
      for ( Node node : GlobalGraphOperations.at( graphDb ).getAllNodes() )
      {
        nodes.add( node );
      }
      tx.success();
    }
    return nodes;
  }
}
```

META-INF/services/org.neo4j.server.plugins.ServerPlugin:

```
com.danmacias.neo4j.plugin.GetAll
```

*(note the ending newline)*

Using neo4j 2.0.2
java version "1.7.0_71"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_71-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.71-b01, mixed mode)

This issue has me on the verge of going insane :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GetAll class should be in a directory in the Jar:

```
com/danmacias/neo4j/plugin/GetAll.class
```

Like usually Java jars are packaged.

Comment: Thank you!  The Scala world has spoiled me, I'll have to keep to Java mindset for a little bit.